# Is there a way to set fields in a sharepoint list based on a linking field, but with values from another list, similar to a JOIN or even a vlookup?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, vlookup, sharepoint-designer

I'd like to set some field values on a newly created list item from another list. For example -

List A is a master list of purchase orders with ONE record per order. The record contains the customer, the address, and some other standard data.

List B is a log of picked parts. Right now, the user types in a PO number, and selects a part from a drop down. I'd like a workflow that updates fields in list B with data pulled from List A, joined on the unique PO number, after the user submits the form.

I've not been able to find a way to do this in Sharepoint Designer, most of what I've read is about lookup fields.

In Excel this would be a vlookup formula. 
In Access this would be a simple join on the PO fields.

I'd like for the user to submit the PO and part, and the workflow retrieve data from List A and populate the same fields in the CurrentItem on List B, so that the new record in List B now contains the "header" data from List A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow for List A, when item created, trigger workflow to update item in list B based on item value in List A.

[image: You can create a workflow for List A, when item created, trigger workflow to update item in list B based on item value in List A.]

Comment: I haven't tried that, thank you- however, the new items aren't created in list A. They're created in list B, and I need the data pulled from A's master list into B's item fields.